# Strange behavior with Git and Visual Studio 2012 projects

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2012

It appears that at some point in time durning commits or pulls that git is giving me issues with my csproj files. I may be wrong but it appears to be an issue.
After a few commits and pulls VS 2012 will show duplicate files in the solution explorer:

[image]

It turns out my initial csproj file includes all my files liek this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include=".\**\*.cs" />
```

however every time I add files or commit / pull the VS2012 adds a line for each file in the project.

How do I avoid this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your hard drive for errors. Those symptoms sound nasty, and file truncation is probably external to VS. Also disable any extensions you have installed to see if one of them is the culprit.

Comment: Are you using any source control?

Comment: @JasonWilliams I have disabled extensions and I am looking into it further, the file issues I have deduced happened before importing into VS so that is solved. How ever I still have VS reporting duplicate files even though they are not duplicated.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Yes I am using Version control, Git to be more specific.

Comment: If you're using source control, check that no merging is occurring on your csproj files when you are checking in - bad merges could possibly cause duplicate entries in the csproj - so it may be outside VS that the duplicates are introduced. If you can narrow down when the duplicates appear (when adding a file to VS? when checking in? etc) it might help you to diagnose it.

Comment: @JasonWilliams It does appear that it may be source control related. My laptop is not showing duplicates, however this morning I pulled my branch down to my desktop and it is showing the duplicates.  This appears to be more of a git question, but how do  I prevent this? I have never sen anythign like this before.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know git well enough to answer that for you - maybe you need to rephrase your question to be about git?

Comment: @JasonWilliams thanks, I have updated my question to hopefully better reflect the issue.